# App Name in Appstore is different than on your mobile device

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I am about to submit my app to the App Store. As you see in the following screenshots, once you open App Store, you could find a very lengthy name of the app. But once you download the app, very short name is shown only. How is it possible?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name under the app icon on the device is the Bundle Display Name.

By default, the Bundle Display Name is the same as the Bundle Name, but you can set it in Xcode by selecting the info.plist file and setting it in the editor.

The Bundle Display Name does not have to match the Bundle Name or the application title that you set in iTunes Connect, however, it must be similar to the application title that you set in the store or Apple will reject the app.

The app store [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#metadata):

> **3.4** App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion

Documentation on [Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html).

Comment: You mean, appstore name comes from the itunesconnect name. Am I right? The name I see on my device, comes from bundle display name?

Comment: @ Marcus, thanks a lot.is there any documents for me to read or to refer? I will accept your answer as a correct answer. But system will be allowing me in 5 min.

Comment: @casillas, I added some document references.

Comment: I the newest guidelines, closest I could find is: "**2.3.8**  [...] _Remember to ensure your metadata, including app name and icons (small, large, Apple Watch app, alternate icons, etc.), are similar to avoid creating confusion._"

Answer (score 1):

Only the Bundle ID of the app needs to match. The makers of that app set the name of the app in iTunes Connect:

[image: itc]

That's the one that is shown in the App Store.

For the name shown under the app, they set this value in their `info.plist`:

[image: plist]

These names are completely independent of eachother, **but**, Apple *does* reject apps where the display name is radically different than the name in the App Store. Main guideline: Don't name your app *Waffles* in the App Store and *Unicorns* on the device.

From the [App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#metadata):

> **3.4** App names in iTunes Connect and as displayed on a device should be similar, so as not to cause confusion

Comment: The name appears on appstore referring the image[1], comes from itunessconnect. The name I see on my device that comes from BundleID and info.plist. Right?

Comment: @casillas Yep - exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The name you type in iTunes connect when creating the app deos not need to match the product name in the app build settings (info plist). Only the bundle id needs to match.